# ROS for industrial networks

Tags: ros, ethercat

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone used ROS to directly talk to devices over some of the more common industrial networks, like DeviceNet, ControlNet, or Profibus.  I know that there is some support within ROS for EtherCat, but it appears to be limited to the PR-2 servo drives.  I would really like to use ROS to directly read/write networked digital and analog IO.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9205/ros-for-industrial-networks/) by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1601 on 2011-02-25

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not aware of any existing integration with your listed networks.  The usual method to do this sort of integration would be to write a driver node which would form a bridge.

There are examples of connecting to other IP based networks with [YARP](http://www.ros.org/browse/search.php?q=yarp) and  [Orocos](http://www.ros.org/browse/search.php?q=orocos).

There are lots of other [drivers](http://www.ros.org/browse/search.php?q=driver) which provide interfaces to other, non IP based, transports.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We provide a wrapper with extensions around the Simple Open Ethercat Master code. This wrapper includes drivers for the most important Beckhoff modules, some custom Ethercat modules and the Kuka Youbot.
The documentation is currently limited ([ROS wiki)](http://www.ros.org/wiki/soem) but we provide a folder with examples on the GIT server: [KUL GIT](http://git.mech.kuleuven.be/?p=robotics/soem.git;a=summary).

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-02-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3